# MD5 in ActionScript

Tags: actionscript, md5

I am trying to build a web based flash application. I am quite new to flash. I would like to develop it in two forms - demo and paid version. For this application to act as a paid version I need to have some kind of serial key. In order to achieve this I googled and came across something like this

`MD5(MD5(thisuri)+thisuri)`

I think 'thisuri' points to the current url page but I don't know how to get that url and I don't know whether '+' acts as a character or an operator.

Can you please help me?

Comment: The above will anyway produce just a MD5 hash... it has nothing to do with the thisuri variable which could be any string.

Comment: Yes, of course, it can be anything. Suppose that 'thisuri' is pointing to website domain name then how do I get that in ActionScript?

Answer (score 11):

It seems that a library exists in AS3.0 : [as3corelib](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib)

> An ActionScript 3 Library that contains a number of classes and utilities for working with ActionScript? 3. These include classes for MD5 and SHA 1 hashing, Image encoders, and JSON serialization as well as general String, Number and Date APIs.

To use it, just download the zip file, decompress it and copy the contents of "src" directory to the root of your project.
Then in your actionscript code, simply do the following :

```
import com.adobe.crypto.MD5;
var hash:String = MD5.hash(”test”);
```

source [in french](http://arnaudgeorgin.blogcity.fr/2009/02/12/utiliser-le-cryptage-md5-en-actionscript-3/)

Answer (score 0):

To add to @Julien's recommendation of using as3corelib, you will also need the advice from this post to get the current url: [Get Current Browser URL - ActionScript 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127962/get-current-browser-url-actionscript-3)

Somehow I think there's a more elegant way to get the url, but I don't remember it.

While this may provide you with some basic check for the paid version, a determined hacker will easily fool this algorithm.  For example, I could fool the environment into thinking that its being served from a domain that you've registered as part of the "paid" version.  Also, since the client has the flash code, they can decompile the binary and potentially see the algorithm you're using.  Depending on what you're offering in the app, this extreme case may or may not be acceptable to you.

Look into more secure authentication mechanisms if you're serious about security.